# Enum and Switch Statement to Map String Array in Swift 4

Tags: algorithm, enums, switch-statement, swift4

I'm using an enum and switch statement in an attempt to map letter combinations to a give string of numbers. This similar to a Phone Words algorithm where you are given a phone number and have to find the possible words mapped from that number. Here, I'm not trying to find the actual english words, necessarily. But rather, just basic `String` of letters.

The code below isn't printing in Playgrounds for some reason.

```
enum Dialpad : Int {
  case zero, one, two, three, four

  var letters : [String] {
    switch self {
    case .zero,.one:
      return []
    case .two:
      return ["a","b","c"]
    case .three:
      return ["d","e","f"]
    case .four:
      return ["g","h","i"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a recursive function that combines `Character` arrays into `String` arrays.

```
func comboArray(_ arrays:[[String]], n:Int,set:inout Set<String>) {
  if n >= arrays.count { return }
  let array = arrays[n]
  if set.isEmpty {
    set = Set(array)
  } else {
    set.forEach { (c1) in
      array.forEach({ (c2) in
        set.insert(c1+c2)
      })
      if !array.isEmpty {
        set.remove(c1)
      }
    }
  }
  comboArray(arrays, n: n+1, set: &set)
}
```

This function should take in a number and map it to the appropriate dial pad letters.

```
func dialPadLetters(number:Int) -> Set<String> {
  let stringNumber = String(number)
  var arrayLetter : [Array<String>] = []
  for c in stringNumber {
    let n = Int(String(c))!
    let letters = Dialpad(rawValue: n)!.letters
    arrayLetter.append(letters)
  }
  var mySet : Set<String> = []
  comboArray(arrayLetter, n: 0, set: &mySet)
  return mySet
}
```

Then, I try to print the possible combinations of letters a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i because the given dial pad numbers are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. (Note that 0 and 1 do not contain dial pad letters.)

```
let theSet = dialPadLetters(number: 1234)

print("\(theSet)")
```

Comment: WFM and prints `["adh", "bdg", "afi", "bdi", "beh", "bdh", "bfg", "adg", "bfi", "aeh", "cdi", "aeg", "bfh", "cfi", "afg", "cfg", "aei", "afh", "bei", "ceg", "cdh", "cei", "adi", "cdg", "ceh", "cfh", "beg"]`

Comment: What does WFM mean?

Comment: @swiftcoder, probably, `works for me`, because the code works for me too just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you playground is broken, because your code works for me and prints `["adh", "bdg", "afi", "bdi", "beh", "bdh", "bfg", "adg", "bfi", "aeh", "cdi", "aeg", "bfh", "cfi", "afg", "cfg", "aei", "afh", "bei", "ceg", "cdh", "cei", "adi", "cdg", "ceh", "cfh", "beg"]`